# Diagonal of the inverse of a 6x6 symmetric partitioned matrix

Tags: matrix-analysis, matrix-inverse, linear-algebra

Let
$$M = \begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\
B & C
\end{bmatrix}$$
in which $A$, $B$ and $C$ are $3 \times 3$ matrices being also symmetric. In fact, they are quite similar, just differing on a single term:
$$A =
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_x \sum_y A(x,y) x^2 & \sum_x \sum_y A(x,y) xy & \sum_x \sum_y A(x,y) x\\
\sum_x \sum_y A(x,y) xy & \sum_x \sum_y A(x,y) y^2 & \sum_x \sum_y A(x,y) y\\
\sum_x \sum_y A(x,y) x & \sum_x \sum_y A(x,y) y & \sum_x \sum_y A(x,y) \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
$B$ and $C$ are exactly the same as $A$ but replacing $A(x,y)$ by $B(x,y)$ and $C(x,y)$ respectively.
If we assume every matrix is non-singular, is there an analytic way to get the diagonal of the inverse of matrix M, that is $M^{-1}_{i,i}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are $A,B,C$ recursively defined? I can't figure out what you mean by this definition...

Comment: Perhaps you can explain how you mean the summation over $x$ and $y$. Are the entries of $A$ polynomials in $x$ and $y$, or do $x$ and $y$ run from $1$ to $k$ ?

Comment: You might consider adding a top-level tag in order to make more people see this question.